# Why are no industrial diode lasers deep cooled?

Tags: optics, visible-light, semiconductor-physics, laser, thermoelectricity

Endurance lasers showed that a 633nm laser diode could lase as low as 621nm when cooled to almost -80C. The wavelength shift for diode lasers can surpass 0.3nm/‘C. From my limited experience industrial and life science diode lasers mostly operate near room temperature. Diode lasers are often already mounted to thermoelectric coolers capable of achieving a temperature delta approaching 100C. Scientific camera sensors are routinely cooled to -80C in this way. Why are there few/no deep cooled lasers operating in the 600-620nm range marketed?

Comment: camera sensors are not lasers, they are cooled to reduce their detector (thermal, shot) noise

Comment: Lasers aren’t particularly efficient, so you need to keep them from getting too hot. Thermoelectric coolers are amazingly inefficient, so pulling all the waste heat out _and_ cooling to -80 is asking too much.

Comment: Cooling a laser below 0 C causes a lot of inconvenience keeping the laser from getting coated in ice. If that's the only way you can find to get a 625 nm laser (for example) then it might be worth it. But if there's another laser available that can do 625 nm at room temperature, it's probably a better choice even if the laser itself costs 10x as much.